# How do Turks and Arabs view each other?

Tags: public-opinion, turkey, middle-east, nationalism, colonialism

There is usually quite a lot of bad blood between the former colonial powers and the former colonies - like between Russia and the former Soviet Republics or Soviet Block countries, between France and its African colonies, etc. I am looking here for the opinion polls on the Arab attitudes to Turkey (as the heir of the Ottoman empire), and vice versa - in a nutshell expanding on [this statement](https://www.trtworld.com/opinion/the-evolving-relationship-between-turkey-and-the-arab-world-12766645):

> Turks were told that the Arabs betrayed them; Arabs were told that the Turks colonised them. Despite the efforts of secular elitists, both sides entered a historic phase in which ties were restored and new relationships built.

Do Arabs see Turkish attempts to play a larger role in the Middle East as continuation of its past colonial ambitions, (as, e.g., the way one often speaks of [*the French policy in Africa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7afrique).)

Comment: If Arabs talk about colonialism, they much more talk about the [Sykes–Picot Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sykes%E2%80%93Picot_Agreement) and the [Treaty of Sèvres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_S%C3%A8vres) as the source of injustices. Most of the blame goes to the USA, the UK and France.

Comment: @ccprog good point. One specific aspect that interests me here is how the colonialism is mitigated (or not) by Muslim solidarity.

Comment: The question is very broad. We're talking about perhaps half-a-billion Arabs and upwards of 100 million Turk-ethnic people if you include for example Tatars. Can you please rephrase it so it becomes clearer what ethnic groups you are asking about and over what issues?

Comment: @StandwithGaza I am mostly interested in what is now politically Turkey and the Arab peninsula+ Palestine (but not North Africa.)

Comment: Even with those limitations the question is to board imho. I suggest you rephrase it to become about a specific *political* issue.

Comment: There's Wikipedia pages on the history of relationships between Turkey and various countries. Perhaps that would be a starting point for a more focused question.

Comment: How about any people living in territories controlled by the Ottoman Empire as of 1914?  And only wrt relations with Turkey itself, not ethnic Turks.  What are polls/sentiment/pronouncements by Arab leaders?  Looks to me like people want to find an excuse not to understand the question.

Comment: Voting to keep open. The close reason (*"This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."*) is incorrect. **There is only one main question** (*"How do Turks and Arabs view each other?"*) and its clarification (*"Do Arabs see Turkish attempts to play a larger role in the Middle East as continuation of its past colonial ambitions?"*). **It's really a single, clear question.**

Comment: Still the question lacks focus. One could write books about it. Concentrating on specific things: is there violence against Turks? How are diplomatic relations? Economic ties?